# Local git push cannot trigger the pipeline of gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci

```yaml
rules:
  - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
```

Modify the code in the gitlab UI and submit it to trigger the gitlab-ci pipeline.
But locally, using the git push command to submit the code, the pipeline will not be triggered.

Include merge_request_event, available in gitlab UI, using git commands locally will not trigger gitlab-ci pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Check first if this is a syntax issue, by removing quotes, as in [this example](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#run-jobs-for-scheduled-pipelines):

```yaml
job:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
  script:
    - make build
```

Comment: it's not work, even if I remove the rules

Comment: Executing git push origin main:main locally cannot trigger the pipeline

Comment: @MoonLi Did you first commit and push your `.gitlab-ci.yml`?

Comment: yes when i commit code in gitlab Ui it behaves fine

Comment: @MoonLi Do you mean the job is trigger hen you make a commit directly on gitlab.com?

Comment: I suspect it's gitlab's problem, but I don't know where to start the investigation

Comment: Do you mean the job is trigger hen you make a commit directly on gitlab.com? ->yes

Comment: @MoonLi Is your repository a public one we could have a look at?

Comment: Is your repository a public one we could have a look at? – > no

Comment: @MoonLi Can you reproduce the same issue, using a dummy public repository? That way, I or other could investigate.

Comment: no, I can't, This gitlab was built by someone else, I don't know the building process